# TextView text aligment is horrible! How to work around it?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I always seem to have the biggest issues with aligning a text on a layout.  Seems like the TextView doesn't measure its text properly.  The reported TextView width and height are a lot bigger than the actual text.  One would expect the TextView width and height to be tightly wrapped around the text.

The image below shows how the number 18 and the text "SEC" are not aligning on the same bottom baseline.  This is due to the larger text height being a lot bigger than the text is. My xml layout can be seen below.

How to achieve better text alignment accuracy?

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/scan_block_1_bg" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/staticCountDown"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvStaticScanning"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:shadowColor="#ffffff"
            android:shadowDy="1.0"
            android:shadowRadius="0.01"
            android:text="SCANNING"
            android:textColor="#878787"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvCountDown"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:shadowColor="#66000000"
            android:shadowDy="-1.0"
            android:shadowRadius="0.01"
            android:text="03"
            android:textColor="#b6b6b6"
            android:textSize="81sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvStaticSeconds"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/staticCountDown"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/staticCountDown"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:shadowColor="#ffffff"
        android:shadowDy="1.0"
        android:shadowRadius="0.01"
        android:text="SEC"
        android:textColor="#878787"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As strange as it may sound if you look at the screen shot provided Both the textviews have the same bottom base alignment. Try putting letters "gj" in tv countdown. You can actually see both will come to have same bottom base alignment. Its better go with padma Kumar's answer.

Comment: Thanks, I started thinking that it had something to do with that...  I do see that there is an option for TextView android:includeFontPadding but it seems like it removes the top padding but not the bottom... I wonder if there is a similar option for such a feature...  If no new answers given in the next few days I will consider Kumar answer as the correct one...

Comment: I believe your answer is the correct one since you mention the cause for the spaces.  I wish there was a way to align texts based on their baseline.

Answer (score 4):

//use this attribute in your TextView

```
 android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/staticCountDown"
```

and `android:layout_marginBottom="-10dp"`

Comment: Well technically we shouldn't have to add paddings to match the text.  The TextView is reporting a width and height much larger than the actual text and this is what is creating problems with text aligment.  Not really a layout issue I believe.

Comment: You don't actually need `marginBottom`, `alignBaseline` should be enough in itself. OP had `alignBottom` in the question and that's what we seen in the screenshot.